# How to hide div after append to another?

Tags: javascript

I've got some kind of drop down menu dynamically appending to differents divs. Problem is, when someone click on "close", then `style.display = "none"` wont work. I can change background, opacity, size but i cant hide it.

Code looks like this:

```
    <style>
        html, body{
            height: 98%;
        }
        #editorViewport{
            width: 90%;
            height: 100%;
            min-width: 400px;
            min-height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        #movingElementsContainer{
            display: none;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        #addStartingElementBtn{
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
        }
        #addStartingElementBtn:hover{
            background-color: #c9eac6;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #elementsMenuContainer{
            width: 150px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            background-color: white;
            min-height: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
        }
        .elementOption{
            width: 90%;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }
        .elementOption:hover{
            border: 1px solid red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

<body>
    <div id="editorViewport">

        <div id="addStartingElementBtn" data-Owner="starting" data-Side="starting" class="openElementsMenu">
            Click!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="movingElementsContainer">
        <div id="elementsMenuContainer" data-Open="false" data-Owner="" data-Side="">
            <div data-Kind="1" class="elementOption">
                One
            </div>
            <div data-Kind="2" class="elementOption">
                Two
            </div>
            <div data-Kind="3" class="elementOption">
                Three
            </div>
            <div data-Kind="99" class="elementOption">
                Close
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function prepareEventHandlers(){
        var openElementsMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("openElementsMenu");
        var event = window.attachEvent ? 'onclick' : 'click';
        for(var i = 0; i < openElementsMenu.length; i++){
            if(openElementsMenu[i].addEventListener){
                openElementsMenu[i].addEventListener('click', elementsMenu, false);
            }else{
                openElementsMenu[i].attachEvent('onclick', elementsMenu);
            }
        }
        var elementOption = document.getElementsByClassName("elementOption");
        for(var i = 0; i < elementOption.length; i++){
            if(elementOption[i].addEventListener){
                elementOption[i].addEventListener('click', selectElementToCreate, false);
            }else{
                elementOption[i].attachEvent('onclick', selectElementToCreate);
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        prepareEventHandlers();
    }

    var totalElements = 0;
    var editorViewport = "editorViewport";
    var selectedElementId = ""; 

    var elementsMenu = function(){
        var elementsMenu = document.getElementById("elementsMenuContainer")
        this.appendChild(elementsMenu);
        elementsMenu.style.display = "block";
        elementsMenu.style.left = 61 + "px";
        elementsMenu.style.top = "0px";
        elementsMenu.setAttribute("data-Open", "true");
        elementsMenu.setAttribute("data-Owner", this.getAttribute("data-Owner"));
        elementsMenu.setAttribute("data-Side", this.getAttribute("data-Side"));
    }
    var selectElementToCreate = function(){
        var dataKind = this.getAttribute('data-Kind');
        var parentNode = document.getElementById(this.parentNode.id);

        alert(dataKind)
        if(dataKind == "99"){
            parentNode.style.display = "none"
            parentNode.setAttribute("data-Open", "false");
            parentNode.setAttribute("data-Owner", "");
            parentNode.setAttribute("data-Side", "");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snLva9bp/)

Many thanks for any advise!

Comment: In fact, your menu is closed once, but it seems like the `open` function triggered again when the user clicking on the `close`.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that too, but honestly i dont have no idea why this is happening..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            var selectElementToCreate = function(e){
            var dataKind = this.getAttribute('data-Kind');
            var parentNode = document.getElementById(this.parentNode.id);

            alert(dataKind)
            if(dataKind == "99"){
                console.log(parentNode);
                parentNode.style.display = "none"
                parentNode.setAttribute("data-Open", "false");
                parentNode.setAttribute("data-Owner", "");
                parentNode.setAttribute("data-Side", "");
                alert("Wont Close :");
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
```

Comment: Thank You, works now fine!. Could explain me what stopPropagation is doing?

Comment: StopPropagation prevents further propagation of the current event. Check your dom and you'll see that you have Button Click and inside there are items of menu. If you click on the item without stopPropagation, your button handles this action too.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving the element into the clicked element.

```
var elementsMenu = document.getElementById("elementsMenuContainer")
    this.appendChild(elementsMenu);
```

At first the menu item's click handler is executed which sets the `display` property to `none` and as the click event bubbles then the event handler of the wrapper element is executed and sets the `display` property to `block`.

You should stop the propagation of the event using `stopPropagation` method of the `event` object.

```
var selectElementToCreate = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var dataKind = this.getAttribute('data-Kind');
    var parentNode = this.parentNode;
    if (dataKind == "99") {
        parentNode.style.display = "none";
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, now I know what have I done wrong and i'll keep in mind. Thanks!